# AWS QuickSight - How to create a calculated field with %like clause

Tags: amazon-quicksight

Looking forward for a way to extract a particular word with 'like' clause from a field already populated.

For example, I have a filed holding dataset like

```
Intel 8175
Intel 3145
Intel 2178
AMD 2149
AMD 1200
```

I need an output to be extract as Intel Only.

```
Expected Output
Intel
Intel
Intel
AMD
AMD
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the way with below logic in calculated filed

```
ifelse(
locate(processor, 'Intel') <> 0, 'Intel', 
locate(processor, 'AMD') <> 0, 'AMD', 
'Others'
)
```